# Resolve jar conflicts with third party jars

Tags: maven, spring-boot

We are developing a spring boot application with a single fat jar with all the dependencies. If we have multiple thirds party jars in our Pom, how can we resolve for some of the conflicting scenarios. For example -

Third party (JarA) has dependency on below artifact-
org.apache.commons
jutil_lang

But the same package & Class is available in commons-lang 2.6 and because of this the other 3rd party jar fails.

Considering we cannot updatethe third party jars, what is the approach for conflict resolutions.